# Need help decompiling unknown application

Tags: legacy, decompiler

I'm trying to rebuild a really old application. The program folder has about 74 files. I have no information about how it was built. And the application can't run on Windows 7 or XP. I am trying to figure out 2 things.

1. What language was likely used to code this
2. Is it possible to
   de-compile the files? If so, what tools can do this?

Here's a list of the file types in the folder, and how many of them there are. I am hoping that these extensions will allow someone to tell me what language was used, and maybe suggest a de-compiler to get some information out of them.

- .EXE x1
- .DAT x1
- no ext  x1
- .K x19
- .M x19
- .COM x2
- .OVL x4
- .RUN x25
- .BAT x1

Answer (score 0):

COM files with OVL are 8 or 16 bit binaries written for DOS. OVL is overlay. BAT is a batch file. DAT is probably a data file. The [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) tool may be helpful in determining what the files actually contain, though the era of the files may mitigate against identification.

Another angle to take is to use a hex editor (like [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)) to look at the first 128 bytes or so of the file as this often helps with file identification. If you're ok with posting that data here, go ahead. Otherwise, email me off-list (bruce dot axtens at gmail dot com) and I'll have a look.